# Strange behaviour with ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm in the process of building a basic database using csv files, and i'm currently testing the select function out when i ran into something strange.

```
private ArrayList<Record> selectField(String selectTerm)
{
    Log.log("Selection " + selectTerm,2,"DB_io");

    ArrayList<Record> ret = new ArrayList<Record>();

    if (titleRow.values.contains(selectTerm))
    {
        Log.log("Adding values to " + selectTerm);
        int ordinal = titleRow.values.indexOf(selectTerm);
        Log.log("Ordinal " + ordinal);
        List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (Record r : data)
        {
            List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
            tempList.add(r.values.get(ordinal));
            Record s = new Record(tempList);
            ret.add(s);
            tempList.clear();
        }

        Log.log("Number of records in ret " + ret.size());
        for (Record t : ret)
        {
            Log.log(t.toString());
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Log.log("keyField does not contain that field");
        return null;
    }

    Log.log("Values " + ret.toString());
    return ret;
}
```

When i do this, the part where it logs t.ToString() shows the record to be empty, whereas if i log it before tempList.clear(), it shows the record to be containing data like it should.

If i move the tempList declaration into the Record r : data loop, then it works fine and the Record t : ret loop works outputs the contents of the record like it should

Why is this?

Edit : Record class

```
public class Record
{
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Record(List<String> terms)
    { 
        this.values = terms;
    }

    public Record(String[] s)
    {
        this.values = Arrays.asList(s);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return values.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Record` instance holds a reference to the `ArrayList` instance you passed to its constructor. Therefore, when you call `tempList.clear()`, you clear the same `List` that your `Record` instance is holding a reference to.

You shouldn't call `tempList.clear()`, since you are creating a new `ArrayList` in each iteration of your loop anyway.

Comment: So thats why it is, i wanted to avoid creating a new arraylist each iteration and then creating a new arraylist inside record, but i guess thats impossible

Comment: @DuskFall you have to create a different `ArrayList` instance for each `Record` instance (regardless of whether you pass it to the `Record` instance from outside or create it inside the `Record` class).

Comment: Does that mean that with my current way of doing it, i'll end up with two instances of the list in memory? Or does the tempList contain the data and then inside record it only contains a reference to tempList?

Comment: @DuskFall `List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();` is redundant, since you are overwriting that instance variable in your constructor, so you are creating an empty ArrayList instance you will never use. If you want to create the instance inside your class, change the constructor's body to `this.values.addAll(terms);`. Then, your outside loop won't have to create a new ArrayList in each iteration - it will be enough to create one ArrayList before the loop and call clear in each iteration.

Comment: Thats what i was looking to do, thanks i'll update it

Answer (score 0):

you are referencing object from more than one place and clear method is cleaning object by setting its reference to null:

instead of `ret.add(s);` you can use `ret.add(s.clone())`;